# How can I fix number of rows in JSF Rich Table?

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces

How can I fix the size of table

Example

I am using below code for table in JSF

```
<rich:dataTable id="incompleteCases"
            align="center" headerClass="content_row" rowKeyVar="row"
            rows="10" 
    </rich:dataTable>
```

Where I want to fix the rows of table to exact 10

With the above code table shrinks when there are less rows than 10

How can I force the rows to remain constant?

**Edit:**

Eg: if I have 35 rows,for 3 pages ,it will display 10 rows but on 4th page because It has 5 rows ,table will shrink .I want to add remaining 5 rows so that it wont resize table.

Rows are dynamically populated.

Comment: You mean like padding the table with blanks or stretching it out to a fixed length?

Comment: If the list that will fill the table has less than 10 items, then just add items with blank (or null) values in it, but **this is a bad idea**.

Comment: @happy, like luiggi says, don't do it. The only way to do this that I know of is to simply insert blank entries in the backing list to the table. But I can't possibly see the benefit of such a requirement. Only drawbacks. Good luck